# Is it possible to somehow indicate that the two widgets have the same state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Suppose there are two identical widgets on different screens in the TabBarView, for example icons and when I change the color of one icon, the second should also change it and repeat all its changes. So it's essentially one element with one View, but in two different places in the tree. My question is, is there any way to make these icons keep a common state or point to the same element in the widget tree. Without any listeners or state management.

My first idea was to have them have the same key, but that of course didn't work.

In short, when I create a widget, can I specify that such a widget already exists in the tree and I should use its state and change with it (be duplicated)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it could be possible without any state management.
The life cycle of the widget will stop you from rebuilding your widgets on the previous screens.

Answer (score 0):

> Specify that such a widget already exists in the tree and I should use its state and change

What you're trying to do is actually, what the flutter framework does, and the way flutter does it is with the use of `Elements` and `RenderObjects`. To understand this in more detail do check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=996ZgFRENMs&t=1s) from the flutter team explaining how flutter renders UI's.

A common paradigm used in in flutter, is the flux architecture which is that of data-down actions up.

So to summarize, you should not need to do this activity of deduplication of your widgets as the framework will take care of it for you. Being that the data is passed from a parent widget to the child, and the parent widget is where the state is stored.

State Management must occur, but the effect of state-managment on the render updating is in most cases negligable.